# jq - How to select objects based on a 'whitelist' of property values

Tags: jq, whitelist

Since an example is worth a thousand words, say I have the following JSON stream:

```
{"a": 0, "b": 1}
{"a": 2, "b": 2}
{"a": 7, "b": null}
{"a": 3, "b": 7}
```

How can I keep all the objects for which the `.b` property is one of `[1, 7]` (in reality the list is much longer so I don't want to do `select(.b == 1 or .b == 7)`). I'm looking for something like this: `select(.b in [1, 7])`, but I couldn't find what I'm looking for in the man page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Doing `$value in $collection` could be achieved using the pattern `select($value == $collection[])`. A more efficient alternative would be `select(any($value == $collection[]; .))`  So your filter should be this:

```
[1, 7] as $whitelist | select(any(.b == $whitelist[]; .))
```

Having the array in a variable has its benefits as it lets you change the whitelist easily using arguments.

```
$ jq --argjson whitelist '[2, 7]' 'select(any(.b == $whitelist[]; .))'
```

Comment: The original question referred to a stream, not an array, in which case you wouldn't need to use `map`.

Comment: Also, note that `[1, 7][]` can be expressed as `(1, 7)`.

Comment: Initially, the question indicated that the input was an array, but that was changed after I had answered.

Comment: Yes my bad for editing the question once I saw your answer, I just meant to make the question more focused. @SantiagoLapresta where's the documentation for the `(1, 7)` construct, I can't seem to find it in the man page.

Comment: @foo: The key is that with commas, the expression is yielding multiple values.  When you use `[]` on an array, that expression is also yielding multiple values.  I guess the relevant section in the manual is on [\[`,`\]](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#,). `[1, 2, 3][]` is equivalent to `1, 2, 3`.

Answer (score 2):

The following approach using index/1 is similar to what was originally sought (".b in [1, 7]"), and might be noticeably faster than using .[] within `select` if the whitelist is large.

If your jq supports --argjson:

```
jq --argjson w '[1,7]' '. as $in | select($w | index($in.b))'
```

Otherwise:

```
jq --arg w '[1,7]' '. as $in | ($w|fromjson) as $w | select($w | index($in.b))'
```

or:

```
jq '. as $in | select([1, 7] | index($in.b))'
```

#### UPDATE

On Jan 30, 2017, a builtin named `IN` was added for efficiently testing whether a JSON entity is contained in a stream. It can also be used for efficiently testing membership in an array. For example, the above invocation with --argjson can be simplified to:

```
jq --argjson w '[1,7]' 'select( .b | IN($w[]) )'
```

If your jq does not have `IN/1`, then so long as your jq has `first/1`, you can use this equivalent definition:

```
def IN(s): . as $in | first(if (s == $in) then true else empty end) // false;
```