# jq - How to select objects based on a 'blacklist' of property values

Tags: json, select, jq, blacklist

Similar to the question answered here: [jq - How to select objects based on a 'whitelist' of property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878915/jq-how-to-select-objects-based-on-a-whitelist-of-property-values), I'd like to select objects based on a blacklist of property values...

The following works fine as a whitelist: `curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=10' | jq --argjson whitelist '["stedolan", "dtolnay"]' '.[] | select(.author.login == $whitelist[]) | {author: .author.login, message: .commit.message}'`

```
{
  "author": "dtolnay",
  "message": "Remove David from maintainers"
}
{
  "author": "stedolan",
  "message": "Make jv_sort stable regardless of qsort details."
}
{
  "author": "stedolan",
  "message": "Add AppVeyor badge to README.md\n\nThanks @JanSchulz, @nicowilliams!"
}
```

The problem is, I want to negate that and only show commits from authors besides 'stedolan' and 'dtolnay'; however, if I use `!=` or `not`, I seem to get the same wrong result:

```
nhenry@BONHENRY:~⟫ curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=10' | jq --argjson blacklist '["stedolan", "dtolnay"]' '.[] | select(.author.login == $blacklist[] | not) | .author.login' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
     14 "nicowilliams"
      2 "stedolan"
      1 "dtolnay"
nhenry@BONHENRY:~⟫ curl -s 'https://api.github.com/repos/stedolan/jq/commits?per_page=10' | jq --argjson blacklist '["stedolan", "dtolnay"]' '.[] | select(.author.login != $blacklist[]) | .author.login' | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
     14 "nicowilliams"
      2 "stedolan"
      1 "dtolnay"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would simply be to use `index` with `not`:

```
.[] | .author.login | select( . as $i | $blacklist | index($i) | not)
```

However, assuming your jq has `all/2`, there is something to be said for using it:

```
.[] | .author.login | select( . as $i | all($blacklist[]; $i != .))
```

If your jq does not have it, then there is still something to be said for using this solution, with `all/2` defined as follows:

```
def all(s; condition): reduce s as $i (true; . and ($i | condition));
```