# Jq using contain with multiple match conditions

Tags: jq

I have json file with multiple object Id's and I need a query that excludes different ids based on naming conventions. These are essentially OR's. I thought I had it with this query but they are still appearing in the output.

If I run the query with them separately I can get it to work, but I need to add a large list.

Works

```
cat file.json | jq '.interface[] | select(.description | contains ("VLL") | not )'
```

Not working

```
cat file.json | jq '.interface[] | select(.description | contains ("VLL"|"2002089"|"otherstuff" ) | not )'
```

Ive tried a few different ways with commas and quoting but no luck.

Am I far off?

I also plan to run this in bash script if that help(probably makes worse)

Thanks

Comment: To do contains OR you would need to use `filter(function)` and do the various tests in the function

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Am I far off?

If you use `test/1` instead of `contains`, and make corresponding adjustments, no:

```
.interface[]
| select(.description | test ("VLL|2002089|otherstuff" ) | not )
```

The argument of test is interpreted as a regex. There are of course alternatives, but if using a regex is appropriate, then `test` would be suitable.

### Blacklist of strings

If you have a blacklist of strings and want to use string equality as the criterion, consider:

```
["VLL","2002089","otherstuff"] as $blacklist
| .interface[]
| select(.description | IN($blacklist[]) | not)
```

Comment: I did get mine to work with adding extra or's, but your method far superior. Thanks

What I did to kind of get it working on mine 
(.description | contains ("VLL") or contains ("2002089") | not )

Comment: I'd avoid `contains` unless it's exactly what you want (which is unlikely).  You could use `index` if you want simple substring matching.  See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141310