# Multiple operations with an array

Tags: json, jq

I'm using an application that depends on a JSON config file and unfortunately, there is no way to configure it for different environments. The configuration file looks like this:

```
{
  "allowed_origin": [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://companydev.com",
    "http://company.com"
  "
}
```

For `dev` we would like to have this:

```
{
  "allowed_origin": [
    "http://localhost",
    "http://companydev.com"
  "
}
```

For `prod`:

```
{
  "allowed_origin": [
    "http://company.com"
  "
}
```

I don't know if it's possible to process the JSON in a single jq pass. To delete the `localhost` this works `. allowed_origin |= map(select(index("http://localhost")|not))`.
But how to do the other one? I tried somethings but I did not have any success.

Comment: Does this SO Q&A about blacklists effectively answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40141310/jq-how-to-select-objects-based-on-a-blacklist-of-property-values If not, please clarify.

Comment: Also, you seem to use `"` instead of `]`.

Comment: What do you mean by "no way to configure it for different environments". How are you planning to feed the output of `jq` to your application that wouldn't apply to simply doing something like changing a symlink for `config.json` from `prod.json` or `dev.json` as necessary?

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

I used `del` to remove an entry instead of `|=` with `map`.

```
#!/bin/bash
env=$1
json=$2

case "$env" in
    (dev)  indices='index("http://company.com")' ;;
    (prod) indices='index("http://company.com"),index("http://localhost")' ;;
    (*) echo Invalid env "$env" >&2 ;;
esac

command="del(.allowed_origin[.allowed_origin|$indices])"
echo "$command"
jq "$command" "$json"
```