# How does a `select (. == ["a","b"][])` predicate work in JQ?

Tags: json, jq

I'm looking for ways to select JSON entries based on an array that I provide as a literal:

```
$ echo '["a","b","c","d"]' | jq '.[] | select (. == ["a","b"][] )'
"a"
"b"
```

In the code above, all entries are selected that are in the `["a","b"]` array. However, I don't understand how the `. == ["a","b"][]` predicate works in detail and would be grateful for an explanation. The tricky part is the right-hand side of `==`.

Related:

- [jq - How to select objects based on a 'whitelist' of property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878915/jq-how-to-select-objects-based-on-a-whitelist-of-property-values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to understanding here is that jq is stream-oriented.  `["a","b"][]` produces a stream, ergo `. == ["a","b"][]` produces a stream.  `select` selects the items that produce truthy values in that stream.

To gain an understanding of how jq works, it often helps to pull things apart.  In the present case, you could begin by trying:

```
echo '["a","b","c","d"]' | jq '.[] | (. == ["a","b"][])'
```

`debug` is also helpful, e.g.

```
echo '["a","b","c","d"]' | jq '.[] | select(debug == ["a","b"][])'
```

Comment: Thanks. I found that rather starting from an array, I could also use the comma operator for the same result `select (. == ("a","b"))`. They key is that `,` is really an operator and not just a delimiter.

Comment: Yes,  one can read [1,2] as: create a list from the stream: 1,2