# Use jq to replace array values from dictionary

Tags: arrays, json, bash, dictionary, jq

I have a dictionary which looks like:

```
cat dictionary.json
[
  {
    "key": "key01",
    "value": "value01"
  },
  {
    "key": "key02",
    "value": "value02"
  },
  {
    "key": "key03",
    "value": "value03",
    "extraProperty": {
      "foo": "bar"
    }
  },
  {
    "key": "key04",
    "value": "value04"
  }
]
```

Then, I have an array which is:

```
echo $array
key01 key02 key03
```

Expected output:

```
value01 value02 value03
```

I have some trouble to make jq using an array which is not json format.
I tried various solutions that I found, but none of them worked.
This post [jq - How to select objects based on a 'whitelist' of property values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34878915/jq-how-to-select-objects-based-on-a-whitelist-of-property-values) seems to solve a similar problem but it doesn't work with my input:

```
echo $array | jq --argfile whitelist dictionary.json 'select(any(.key== $whitelist[]; .value))'
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
```

I also tried to use

```
jq -n --arg array $array --argfile whitelist dico.json 'select(any(.key== $whitelist[]; .valuee))'
jq: error: key02/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
key02
jq: 1 compile error
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. The goal is that you add some code of your own to your question to show at least the research effort you made to solve this yourself.

Comment: Thanks for welcoming. I edited my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here

```
jq -r --arg array "$array" \
  'from_entries | .[($array | split(" "))[]]' \
  dictionary.json
```

Output

```
value01
value02
value03
```

See `man jq` for further information.

Comment: Last question: is that possible to display the original key when not found in the dictionary?
Like:
Input:

    key01
    key02
    key03
    notFound

Output:

    value01
    value02
    value03
    notFound

Comment: Ask another question about it.

Answer (score 1):

Using `INDEX/2`, which constructs a dictionary:

```
echo 'key01 key02 key03' |
  jq -Rr --argfile dict dictionary.json '
    INDEX($dict[]; .key) as $d
    | split(" ") | map( $d[.]|.value )
    | join(" ")'
```

yields:

```
value01 value02 value03
```

If your jq does not have `INDEX`, then now would be an excellent time to upgrade to jq 1.6; alternatively, you can simply snarf its def by googling: `jq "def INDEX"`

Comment: I should have added that I have to use jq 1.5

Comment: So copy the def, available by googling `jq “def INDEX"`